# How to open up a form from another form in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

This I thought would be easy. I have not used VB.NET all that much, and I am trying to open up a form from a button click. The form will not show and I get a null exception error.

What is wrong with the code?

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim A
    A = AboutBox1
    A.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim A As New AboutBox1 // A.ShowDialog`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
                          Handles Button3.Click

    Dim box = New AboutBox1()
    box.Show()

End Sub
```

Comment: It should, yes.  Here's the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Any thought as to why this would open the new form beneath the calling form?

Comment: I changed form.show() to form.show(me) and it works as intended now.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use showdialog

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
                      Handles Button3.Click

     dim mydialogbox as new aboutbox1
     aboutbox1.showdialog()

End Sub
```

Comment: What if I want it to be any form? Maybe one that I created myself?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
Dim MyForm As New Form1
MyForm.Show()
```

or rather:

```
MyForm.ShowDialog()
```

to open the form as a dialog box to ensure that user interacts with the new form or closes it.

Answer (score 1):

'Let say you have two forms i.e Form1 and Form2
'Inside Form1 Let say you have a button called 'Show';
'If you want to access Form2 from Form1,double click on Button Show and type the code as follows:-
Form2.show()

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form2.ShowDialog()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
 Button1.Click

        Dim n As New Form2
        n.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

You may like to first create a dialogue by right clicking the project in solution explorer and in the code file type

```
dialogue1.show()
```

that's all !!!