# Re-Open current Form on button click in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio, button, click

I am using VB.Net to developing an application.

Is there any way to open the current form in button click. Let's say that I'm in Form1 and if the user clicks the button "No" then the app should open Form1 again, else if the answer is "Yes" then it should open Form2. How can I make it open the same form (Form1) again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20622419/7124761

Comment: Just create a [**new**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/new-operator) instance of the form and show it like you would with any other form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new instance of Form1 and Form2, 
Then handle it in conditional statements

```
'No Button
Dim f1 = new Form1();
f1.show();
Me.close();

'Yes Button
Dim f2 = new Form2();
f2.show();
Me.close();
```